# Get_Attribute("href") is Returning Some Weird Value From Spotify

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, spotify

I've been trying to learn selenium and i decided to take up a fun project, so i am trying to scrape a Spotify Playlist! But When I tried to get links of an artist's page through Get_Attribute("href"), its returing this:

```
[[...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...]]
```

this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd

website= "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6iwz7yurUKaILuykiyeztu"
path= "C:/Users/ashut/Downloads/Misc Docs/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"

service=Service(executable_path=path)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get(website) 

containers=driver.find_elements(by="xpath",value='//div[@data-testid="tracklist-row"]/div[@aria-colindex="2"]/div')

titles = []
artists = []
links = []

for container in containers:
    title=container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./a/div').text
    artist=container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./span/a').text
    link=container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./span/a').get_attribute("href")
    titles.append(title)
    artists.append(artist)
    links.append(links)
    
mydict={'titles':titles,'artists':artists,'links':links}
artistslist= pd.DataFrame(mydict)
artistslist.to_csv('list_of_artist.csv')
```

this is what the csv looks like

```
,titles,artists,links
0,Can't Stop My Shine,Chronik KID,"[[...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...]]"
1,Toxic,Donatello Yii,"[[...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you an alternative solution using re. I also refactored a little your code. Let me know if something is not clear

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

website = "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6iwz7yurUKaILuykiyeztu"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get(website)

time.sleep(5)
container_xpath = '//div[@data-testid="tracklist-row"]/div[@aria-colindex="2"]/div'

titles = [x.text for x in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=container_xpath+'/a/div')]
artists = [x.text for x in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=container_xpath+'/span/a')][0:len(titles)]
links = [x for x in re.findall( 'https://open.spotify.com/track/\w{22}', driver.page_source)][0:len(titles)]


mydict = {'titles': titles, 'artists': artists, 'links': links}
artistslist = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
artistslist.to_csv('list_of_artist.csv')
```

Comment: hey! thanks a lot! after you answered it i was still confused as to why my method wasn't working and it turned out to be a dumb typo ;(
links.append(link)

Comment: i am still confused tho, why is it not returning the list of all songs, it only returns like 20-30 out of the 103

Comment: try to zoom the page using  driver.get('chrome://settings/')
driver.execute_script('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(0.01);') . Maybe scrolling the navigator can help. The solution is not immediate.

Comment: the data you need is  rendered dinamically.